# Checking if a vertex belongs to a vertex group in python

Tags: python, vertex-groups

I'm trying to check whether or not a vertex belongs to a particular group, I've seen a couple methods, I'm wondering why the following does not move any vertices.

```
for v in ob.data.vertices:
  if v.groups.find("Group") >= 0:
     v.co[0]=5 + offset
```

Just to be clear, There is a vertex group with the given name with vertices assigned, but nothing is moved.  Am I using the find method wrong?  Or totally misunderstanding what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75240/28015

Answer (score 15):

What you basically want is something like this:

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
gi = ob.vertex_groups["Group"].index # get group index
for v in ob.data.vertices:
  for g in v.groups:
    if g.group == gi: # compare with index in VertexGroupElement
      v.co[0] = 5
```

[`v.groups`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.MeshVertex.html#bpy.types.MeshVertex.groups) is a collection of VertexGroupElements. [VertexGroupElement](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.VertexGroupElement.html#bpy.types.VertexGroupElement) contains group (as index) and weight (as float [0,1]).

[`find`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html#bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection) can not find anything, because v.groups does not contain any keys.

Comment: So what is the find method meant for?  It seems useless.

Comment: Collections are container classes and have a general purpose interface. In this special case find is not useful but it might be in other cases where the collection actually contains keys. For more information see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866987/what-is-the-definition-of-interface-in-object-oriented-programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866987/what-is-the-definition-of-interface-in-object-oriented-programming)

Answer (score 3):

There is a quick yet counter-intuitive way to check whether a vertex with a certain index belongs to a group or not. Whenever you call [`your_object.vertex_groups[GROUP_NAME].weight(i)`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.types.VertexGroup.html?highlight=weight#bpy.types.VertexGroup.weight) to check the weight of a vertex, if that vertex is not present in the mentioned group, this method raises a `RuntimeError`. You can use it. Here's the code:

```
import bpy

GROUP_NAME="Group"

obj=bpy.context.active_object
data=obj.data
verts=data.vertices

for vert in verts:
    i=vert.index
    try:
        obj.vertex_groups[GROUP_NAME].weight(i)
        #if we get past this line, then the vertex is present in the group
        vert.co.x = 5 + offset # or whatever value you want            
    except RuntimeError:
       # vertex is not in the group
       pass
```

Basically, you iterate over all the vertices in your mesh, trying to get their weights (but here we don't save them to a variable, because for your particular task you don't need the values of weights). If a vertex is present in your group, the `weight()` returns its weight value, which is discarded immediately, and then it moves to the next line where it translates the vertex along the x axis. But, if a vertex is not present in the group, it raises `RuntimeError` exception, thus skipping the vertex translation part. `pass` means "*do nothing*", so it simply moves along to the next vertex.

Comment: Nice ad-hoc solution with `try` / `except`